# Babylon.js, how to remove a mesh from scene?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

How can I remove mesh from scene in Babylon.js in runtime? Tried to search, didn't find, also tried to view the scene methods in debugger, also can't find.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just have to use mesh.dispose();

Comment: regarding optimization : i reckon it is usefull to set the mesh variable to null after the dispose call (to tell the GC he can collect), right?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are finding for is this .

This method removes the specific mesh .

```
scene.removeMesh( mesh name );
```

Here is the example https://playground.babylonjs.com/#3UW6W3#2